# When developing with Codewind, how do I set environment variable values in developer runtime?

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, microclimate

[Codewind](https://www.eclipse.org/codewind/) has the notation of a [Linked Project](https://www.eclipse.org/codewind/linking-your-projects.html) that lets a person define an environment variable which will hold the host name of the deployed Linked Project.

However, how does a person define and set other environment variables that get will be visible in the local developer Docker runtime deployment? For example, environment variables to hold the user name or password for an external resource like a database.

Comment: If variables are supported in this dialog (as is the case in launch configurations), you can pass the local environment variables. For example, `${env_var:FOO}` as value is the value of the environment variable `FOO`.

Comment: Hmm - I think you are talking about Eclipse's stand Run/Debug Launcher.  As far as I can tell Codewind does not use Eclipse's standard Launchers or even the Eclipse build.

I believe the Eclipse Codewind plugin appears to really just monitor the local Eclipse project and then delegate to a Codewind runtime (that is either in a person's local Docker container environment or a remote Codewind that is hosted Kubernetes environment) the building and launching of the my code.

Comment: These Eclipse variables can be used in several places, not only in launch configurations. But I do not know if Codewind supports this.